# Why do I need to use app namespace in menu items when using AppCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

Previously, before using `AppCompat`, I was using `SherlockActionBar` to support Android 2.3.

The following menu works just perfect under `SherlockActionBar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_browser"
        android:title="@string/menu_browser"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarBrowserIcon"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="@string/menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarShareIcon"/> 
</menu>
```

However, even since migrating to `AppCompat`, I realize the above menu doesn't work. I need to use `app` namespace, in order to make it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_browser"
        android:title="@string/menu_browser"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarBrowserIcon"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="@string/menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarShareIcon"/> 
</menu>
```

Why is this so? What is the difference comparing to `SherlockActionBar`, which makes `app` namespace unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes provided by libraries (or by the app itself) are suppose to be namespaced in order to avoid conflicts/collisions.

ActionBarSherlock masks this behavior by naming the attribute `android:showAsAction`. (As opposed to a `showAsAction` attribute in the `android` namespace): https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__attrs.xml

Comment: Why Google doesn't make their changes equivalent to Jake Wharton's? Isn't that's more convenient for App developers?

Comment: Convenient, yes. Correct, no. Namespaces exist for a reason.